# How to remove buttons from first and last page only?

Tags: javascript, html

So i need help with removing the previous button from first page, and next button from last page. 
Here is my script, it have some cyrillic characters inside, but dont get distracted by them.

```
<div class="container">
  <img id="myImg" src="step1.png">
  <button class="btn1" onclick='next()'>Напред</button>
  <button class="btn4" onclick='prev()'>Назад</button>
</div>

<script>
var curPage=1;
function next(){
    curPage++;
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "step"+curPage+".png";
}

function prev(){
  curPage--;
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "step"+curPage+".png";
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: you can use :last-child and :first-child in CSS, please research in google )

Comment: please show your efforts on what you are trying to achieve? The community will help and correct you.

Answer (score 1):

*You could do that only if you know how many pages there are.*

```js
var img = document.getElementById("image");
var previousBtn = document.getElementById("previous");
var nextBtn = document.getElementById("next");

var currentPage = 1;
update();

var maxPage = 4;

function update() {
  img.src = "http://your_url.com/image" + currentPage + ".jpg";  
  if (currentPage === 0) {
    previousBtn.classList.add("disabled");
  } else {
    previousBtn.classList.remove("disabled");
  }
  if (currentPage === maxPage) {
    nextBtn.classList.add("disabled");    
  } else {
    nextBtn.classList.remove("disabled");  
  }
}

function next() {
  currentPage++;
  update();
}

function previous() {
  currentPage--;
  update();
}
```

```css
button.disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="previous" onclick="previous()">previous</button>
  <img src="" id="image" />
  <button id="next" onclick="next()">next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Whole thing is 11 pages, and all of them is Png pictures with the buttons next and previous.

Comment: Is it possible to give you my whole code, and u help me with what should i do, it will mean alot, as it my first day at work and i need to perform good. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: your answer is in es6 he asked for a solution in Vanilla JavaScript

Comment: You just have to replace `maxPage = 4` by `maxPage = 11` and to replace `span.innerHTML = currentPage;` by the line you wrote in your message `document.getElementById("myImg").src = "step"+curPage+".png";`.

Comment: @xitas As ES is the standard and the 6th version is the most popular, I am pretty sure it could not go wrong with this.

Comment: @robinvrd Thanks for the fast response, but this is not working.Maybe i am just stupid...

Comment: @KaloyanAngelov I just edited my answer to fit with an image example. Of course, the link of the images are fake one.

Comment: So guys i tried a couple of things and now even the buttons doesnt work...
  document.getElementsByClassName("btn1").style.display = 'inline-block';
  document.getElementsByClassName("btn4").style.display = 'inline-block';
  if(curPage == 1)
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn4").style.display = 'none';
  if(curPage == 11)
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn1").style.display = 'none';

Comment: ive tried and even changed some of the things but its still not working, and even the buttons dont work now, however thanks for the help,and if i come up with a solution i will post it here :)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("btn1")` selects all the elements with the classname `btn1`, so it returns an array. If you got only one element with `btn1` class, you should consider using HTML attribute `id` and then use `document.getElementById("btn1")` or you could use the first element of the array with this class `document.getElementsByClassName("btn1")[0]`.